# I cannot redirect to another page in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. I am trying to make a Login Page, when I press the Login button, I want to enter the Home Page I made with React in the same way, but when I use Link or Route commands, the screen becomes completely white without giving any error.  It works properly when I delete the code related to redirection.

```
import React from "react";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App_login.css'
import logo from "./assets/resim.png"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sifre from './App_sifre'
import Anasayfa from './App_anasayfa'
import Login from './App_login'


function App() { 
  return (    
    <body className="bg">   
      <div className="container" >
        <div className="card card-body mt-5 pb-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded ">

        <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        
        <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element= {<Login />} />
        <Route path='/sifre' element= {<Sifre />} />
        <Route path='/anasayfa' element= {<Anasayfa />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
         
          <h2 className="text-center text-info ">DMS Planlama Sistemi</h2>
          <div className="row mt-5 pb-5">
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mb-5">
              <img src={logo} alt="login" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
                  <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı adınız" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="pwd" style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>Şifre:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="şifreniz" id="pwd" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group form-check">
                  <label className="form-check-label">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /> Beni Hatırla
                    <label><a href="şifremi unuttum/şifre yenileme.html" to="/sifre" style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>Şifremi unuttum</a></label>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" href="anasayfa/anasayfa.html">
                  <Link to="/anasayfa"> Login</Link>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </body> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to use Link and Route commands by importing the files I want to route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the body tag because it already exists in the index.html file. For the routes, the path and component pairing seems a bit odd, try using "/" for the homepage and "/login" for the login component. In `<App />` component :

```
import React from "react";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App_login.css'
import logo from "./assets/resim.png"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sifre from './App_sifre'
import Anasayfa from './App_anasayfa'
import Login from './App_login'


function App() { 
  return (    
     <>
       <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element= {<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='/login' element= {<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path='/sifre' element= {<Sifre />} />
          <Route path='/anasayfa' element= {<Anasayfa />} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
     </>
```

Because I saw this is a login form, that's why I suggest you create a "/login" route with the `<LoginPage />` element. Also, something a bit unusual, why are you using the `Link` tag inside the form button? That's odd, and don't do that because forms are usually used for submission, not navigation. If you want to create navigation using `Link`, try placing it outside the form. Here's the content of the `<LoginPage />` component:

```
export default function LoginPage () {
 return (
      <div className="container" >
        <div className="card card-body mt-5 pb-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded ">
          <h2 className="text-center text-info ">DMS Planlama Sistemi</h2>
          <div className="row mt-5 pb-5">
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mb-5">
              <img src={logo} alt="login" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
                  <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı adınız" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="pwd" style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>Şifre:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="şifreniz" id="pwd" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group form-check">
                  <label className="form-check-label">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /> Beni Hatırla
                    <label><a href="şifremi unuttum/şifre yenileme.html" to="/sifre" style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>Şifremi unuttum</a></label>
                  </label>
                </div>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                    submit
                  </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
)
}
```

And the most suspicious thing to me is perhaps the mistake you made is in the import-export part of the component.

```
import Sifre from './App_sifre'
import Anasayfa from './App_anasayfa'
import Login from './App_login'
```

Try looking again at the ***Chrome console*** errors, it might appear there.

Answer (score 0):

First make the following changes to your `index.js`, your code might not look exactly like this but the important thing is to add the `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";` and then wrap the `<App />` with the `<BrowserRouter>  </BrowserRouter>` tags.

So it should look something like this:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Then in your App.js do the following: (1/ Changes were made to what was the the `<BrowserRouter>` section.  These tags were removed from this page and moved to the index.js above. 2/ Changes were made the button with the `Link to=" "`. )

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App_login.css'
import logo from "./assets/resim.png"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sifre from './App_sifre'
import Anasayfa from './App_anasayfa'
import Login from './App_login'

function App() { 
  return (    
    <body className="bg">   
      <div className="container" >
        <div className="card card-body mt-5 pb-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded ">


      <div>      
        <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' component={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/sifre' component={<Sifre />} />
        <Route path='/anasayfa' component={<Anasayfa />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
         
          <h2 className="text-center text-info ">DMS Planlama Sistemi</h2>
          <div className="row mt-5 pb-5">
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mb-5">
              <img src={logo} alt="login" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
                  <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı adınız" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="pwd" style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>Şifre:</label>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="şifreniz" id="pwd" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group form-check">
                  <label className="form-check-label">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /> Beni Hatırla
                    <label><a href="şifremi unuttum/şifre yenileme.html" to="/sifre" style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>Şifremi unuttum</a></label>
                  </label>
                </div>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                    <Link to="/anasayfa"> Login</Link>
                  </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </body> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note, I replaced your button with the following (removing your href in the button tag and relying just on the Link to= ... ):

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
  <Link to="/anasayfa">Login</Link>
</button>
```

Also, please note, in your code, you defined that you are going here: `to="/anasayfa"` if you were intending on going here `to="/"` you can change the path so it would look like this:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
  <Link to="/">Login</Link>
</button>
```

Changed the button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: didn't work I get the same error.

Comment: `<Link to="/anasayfa"> Login</Link>`  when I delete this command, the page works properly, when I add it, the screen is white again, am I using the link command wrong? I tried what you said and the result is the same

Comment: Should work now: 1/ notice the changes to index.js (at the very top of the answer). 2/ `<BrowserRouter>` tags were removed from App.js 3/ and notice the changes made to the button on App.js